# Netbeans doesn't applies changes to the code

Tags: java, netbeans, netbeans-8

I've been asked to modify a java desktop application (I've never worked on java desktop application).

I have been gaven a project, that I opened with **Netbeans 8.0.2**. Something weird happens.

If I edit the code and then I run the project the changes **are not applied**.
If I build the project and then I run the just created file (project/dist/filename.jar) the changes are applied.

This weird behaviour happens only if I edit this project on Netbeans. If I edit this project with Eclipse I'm able to see the changes and I'm able to see the changes also on my own projects created on Netbeans.

The problem seems to be: **the project I've been gaven + Netbeans**.

Do you have any idea about the issues?

Thank you man

Comment: editing the code doesn't change the compiled files. without compilation, no change has been made. This is not "weird behaviour", this is expected behaviour. It's possible your intellij is configured to build on every save

Comment: After I save the code isn't the code automatically compiled?

Comment: no. save is just saving the .java file. your build compiles it. but, several ide's provide the option to configure it so that on a save, your code is compiled. doesn't mean it's active

Comment: If I try to build the project, Netbeans says that is not necessary doing it, since the project is compiled at any saving. I suppose that this means the auto-compilation is enabled.

Comment: it is compiled to a .jar, right? and you are executing said jar? the classes in that jar are not changed by your compilation, only by a build. besides: if you try to re-create the jar while your application is still running, that 'll throw errors/exceptions

Comment: Yes is compiled to a .jar. So, how can I launch, from Netbeans, the app with the edited code? Should I do "right click on project -> build" and then "right click on project -> run"? If I do this, Netbeans launch the application without changes.
THis problem happens only on the project I've been gaven. If I create my own project I have no problem seeing the changes.

Answer (score 2):

- Right click on the project name, then click on `properties`.
- Goto `Build -> Compile`.
- There tick `Compile on Save`.
- Click `OK`.

[image]

---

This will compile your project every time you save it. Usually all files automatically are saved before running. So the changes you made should appear.

Comment: Thank you man, but I have already this settings. The problem happens only when I try to work on the project I've been gaven using NetBeans.
If I open the project with Eclipse I have no problem and I have no problem when I create my own project on Netbeans

Comment: NetBeans and Eclipse are two different IDEs. Their settings may be different. If so, something working on Eclipse may not work on NetBeans. Does the issue still there after changing these settings in NetBeans?

Comment: I am forced to use NetBeans, and I don't understand how this IDE works. I have it enabled, and it does not work as expected. I unchecked it and now it runs fine. Why is it always that Java IDEs are complicated to configure?

Answer (score 2):

In Netbeans, Recompile the classe with F9.

[image]

Comment: Why doesn't NetBeans Compile the file automatically?

Answer (score 0):

Try selecting the right profile for compilation. under project properties -> Configurations it selects  by default. Change that to the profile which your project it pointing at. If your source code is directly connected to GIT hub, ensure that the branch and profile name both match. I solved it that way.

[image: Project Properties]